# An ever increasing sequence

Tags: number-sequence

The following sequence contains numbers that are ever increasing.

```
1, 8, 81, 1024, ...
```

What comes next?

Comment: [OEIS](http://oeis.org/A007778)

Comment: I know it wasn't exactly a difficult puzzle but is there a reason this was downvoted? Or is that just it?

Comment: I think the issue is probably that it's too easy and is already posted elsewhere on the web.  [If you Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=1+8+81+1024&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) these numbers, you'll quickly find the same puzzle. Going for something unique/original will likely get upvoted.

Comment: @DanRussell I understand that posting an original puzzle will gather upvotes, but for this getting downvotes because it's asked on another site is daft in my opinion and an easy puzzle to someone is hard to someone else. But anyway downvotes are there to express opinion, not complaining trying to learn.

Comment: I suspect the downvotes are also because denizens of this site have come to expect *creative*, *original*, *clever* puzzles.  This one doesn't really match any of those criteria.  It's rather boring and unimaginative.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain Well people obviously do not like it so it's going anyway, or not I forgot about the answer thing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't very difficult

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Can you point me to the place that says that easy puzzles are off-topic for this site?

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain; I suspect the downvotes are also because denizens of this site have come to expect creative, original, **clever** puzzles. This one doesn't really match any of those criteria. It's rather boring and unimaginative. – GentlePurpleRain♦ 4 hours ago

Comment: I never said it was off-topic.  I just said it wasn't a great puzzle.  The downvotes have demonstrated that.  We only close questions if they don't actually meet the criteria for posting, which this one does.

Comment: @Jon: That's not closeworthy. Close votes don't mean "I don't like this" - they should only be used for things that are actually not acceptable for the site.

Comment: @Deusovi; understood

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The sequence follows:

> $n^{n+1}$

So the next value is:

> $5^6 = 15625$

Comment: Figured it wouldn't take long

Comment: I'm confused how 1 gets to 8 with this formula?

Comment: @Jason_ look at the below answer by Sconibulus

Answer (score 6):

The answer is

> $15625$.  The formula is $x^{x+1}$

Examples:

> $1=1^2$, $8=2^3$, $81=3^4$, $1024=4^5$

Comment: Never knew 21 seconds could make such a big difference...